# highlighting selected item in custom list view using context menu?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, contextmenu

I've been trying to set my background colour on this list view and with following multiple tutorials it just doesn't come up, yet no errors are shown.

What I've got is an xml file called colours in the values folder:

```
<resources>
    <drawable name="red_colour">#6D0E0E</drawable>
</resources>
```

Which links to an xml in the drawable folder:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_activated="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/red_colour">
</item>

</selector>
```

I've tried placing the following code android:background:@id"colourhighlight.xml"
literally everywhere based on various tutorials yet no luck?

Any advice? Please help...

I've got one main class with a context menu:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_contacts);

        // The contacts from the contacts content provider is stored in this cursor
        mMatrixCursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id","name","photo","details"} );

        // Adapter to set data in the listview
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
                R.layout.lv_layout,
                null,
                new String[] { "name","photo","details"},
                new int[] { R.id.tv_name,R.id.iv_photo,R.id.tv_details}, 0);

        // Getting reference to listview
        final ListView lstContacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_contacts);

        // Setting the adapter to listview
        lstContacts.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Creating an AsyncTask object to retrieve and load listview with contacts
        ListViewContactsLoader listViewContactsLoader = new ListViewContactsLoader();

        // Starting the AsyncTask process to retrieve and load listview with contacts
        listViewContactsLoader.execute();

        //Selecting and highlighting the elements in the listview
        lstContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                view.setActivated(true);
            }
        });

        //Creating the context menu and the options for it
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lst_contacts);
        listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        listview.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                count = count+1;
                mode.setTitle(count + " Contacts Selected");


            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

                MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.contact_context_menu, menu);

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                switch(item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.delete_id:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), count + " Contacts Deselected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        count = 0;
                        mode.finish();
                        return true;
                        //break;
                    default:
                       return false; //break;
                }

                //return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

            }
        });

    }
```

lv_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
        android:maxHeight="80dp"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_photo"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_photo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/tv_details"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_photo"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/iv_photo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ankhit.saveme.UserContacts"
    android:background="@drawable/colourhighlight"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lst_contacts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/instructions"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="showInstructions"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) 
{
    try 
    {
        final int checkedCount = listView.getCheckedItemCount();
        mode.setTitle(""+checkedCount);

        if (checked)
        {
            adapter.setNewSelection(position, checked);                    
        }
        else 
        {
            adapter.removeSelection(position);                 
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

add these methods in your adapter class

```
private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> mSelection = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
public void setNewSelection(int position, boolean value) 
{
    mSelection.put(position, value);
}

public boolean isPositionChecked(int position) 
{
    Boolean result = mSelection.get(position);
    return result == null ? false : result;
}

public Set<Integer> getCurrentCheckedPosition() {
    return mSelection.keySet();
}

public void removeSelection(int position) {
    mSelection.remove(position);
}

public void clearSelection() {
    mSelection = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
}
```

call this method inside `getView()` method of adapter it works properly

```
convertView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
if (mSelection.get(position) != null) 
{
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.message_selector_holo_blue));
                }
```

Comment: @Rakesh...Could you please specify the adapter class(in the async one)? Also the convertview should be called in my setOnItemClick listener?

Comment: want to access listview row??

Comment: I found a way around it: could you help me with this case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021329/context-menu-selecting-color-with-listview-recycling

Answer (score 0):

If you want highlighting selected row completely then change the background color of the convertview

```
lstContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));


        }
    });
```

Comment: @Rakesh...That did not work...mContext could not be recognised so I changed it view.getResources...however, when I long click to get the context bar and try selecting colour doesn't stay or come up.

Comment: Remove mContext and write getResources() method only it will work successfully....

Comment: So it works but not completely. My context menu is on a Long Click then it counts the number of ones I've selected but the colour doesn't appear there...However, when I just select normally without the long click its highlights the items but it highlights every few down in the list I'm assuming this is because the list is being recycled? anyway of keeping the colour to just the items i literally press on Long click?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29021329/context-menu-selecting-color-with-listview-recycling