# MultiChoiceModeListener not from long press

Tags: android, listview

Is there any possibility to use MultiChoiceModeListener or something similar which could be called from action bar button to get contextual action bar because by default it is executed after long press on list item? Right now I’m implementing  `onItemClick` method and then call 
`onItemCheckedStateChanged(actionMode, position, id, true);` but it seems to be wrong. How shouid I do this in proper way? Also there is problem with checking item selected and change its background even after user setSelected method and set `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` atribute.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommended you visit official guide website [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu), the official implementation of the ActionMode. In addition to use long press , you can invoke the contextual ActionMode by:

```
AbsListView.setItemChecked(int position, boolean value)
```

to cause ActionMode create and show.

Answer (score 0):

refer this link for selecting multiple rows from listview

it works for me

i hope it help you

[highlighting selected item in custom list view using context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976702/highlighting-selected-item-in-custom-list-view-using-context-menu/28978811#28978811)